# save a new RDF document with graphite

Tags: php, rdf

I'm new to semantic web, and I'm going to build a semantic web application with PHP. I'm using Graphite and ARC library, but I can't find any good tutorial about how create and save a new RDF document. What I'm going to do is to get some registration information from the user and save it into an RDF file for later usage. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Once you've got your data loaded into a Graphite graph, you can use the `serialize` method of the  [Graphite class](http://graphite.ecs.soton.ac.uk/#graphiteclass) to get something that you can write to file:

> **print $graph->serialize( [$serializer="RDFXML"] );**
>
> Returns the serialization of the entire RDF graph in memory using one of Arc2's serializers. By default the RDF/XML serializer is used, but others (try passing "Turtle" or "NTriples") can be used - see the Arc2 documentation.